# how to pass props to modal on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I just want to pass props from child to parent by button click but when i pass renderCreateQuizzes(value) it pass props but last modal component empty it again

```
function CreateQuiz() {

 const RenderCreateQuizzes = () => {
  return(
   <div><div>
   )
  }
```

this is the render component where i need props from the button on click of form function below

```
const form = () => {
  return (
    <MappedElement
      data={quizzeValue}
      renderElement={(value, index) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <span className="question-text flex-08">
              {index + 1}. {value.text}
            </span>
            <Button
              className="c-button c-button-primary-light button-with-loading"
              onClick={() => {
                setCreateQuizzes(true);
              }}
            >
              Update
            </Button>
          </div>
        );
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

this is the modal when state true modal show

```
return(
   <CCardWrapper className="c-card-wrapper w-100 p-0 flex-1">
    {CForm()}
  </CCardWrapper>

 <CModal
    show={createQuizzesModal}
    className="center small"
    onHide={() => setCreateQuizzes(false)}
  >
    {RenderCreateQuizzes()}
  </CModal>
)
```

Comment: Can you show where `<Form/>` is being used/ where its being called at?

Comment: before modal jsx

Comment: Can you share the code ? currently i do not see <Form/> being called anywhere

Comment: i updated please check

Comment: You do understand that `{CForm()}` naming convention is different from `const form` ? just make it const `CForm = () ...`

Comment: its a typping mistake actually its const CForm=()

Comment: Want to help more, can you make a codesandbox of this so i can debug